# How to use the GoogleVis R package from a remote machine?

Tags: r, remote-server, googlevis

I want to be able to use the `googleVis` package from a remote machine. I use it all the time in my local machine when coding in R to visualize dataframes with the function `gvisTable`, like this

```r
library(googleVis)
Table <- gvisTable(Stock, 
                   formats=list(Value="#,###"))
plot(Table)
```

Running the code above will open a tab in your browser showing a table.

But when I try to use it from an EC2 instance I get the error message

```
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: x-www-browser: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: firefox: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: google-chrome: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
 xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:20403/custom/googleVis/TableID14e933f6ab86b.html'
```

Is there a way I van forward the results from googlevis to my browser?